# Button actions not working correctly on android v9+, but works on v4-8

Tags: php, android, mysql, apk

My application works from android 4 and I assumed that by generating it this way it will work correctly on android 9, 10 etc.

But when entering the application on devices that use android 9 they cannot register or log in correctly, since the buttons are unresponsive. However in other versions of android they work perfectly.

..............................................

```
public class LoginRequestion extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL="http://trabajosparamedicos.com.ar/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public LoginRequestion(String usuario, String contrasena, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("usuario", usuario);
        params.put("contrasena", contrasena);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;

    }
}
```

Comment: No one is going to go and download your app.  Please provide the relevant/problematic code within the body of your question (and format it appropriately).  Let us know what debugging you have already done to narrow down the problem and what the results of it were.  Let us know of any error messages. What exactly does "Buttons do not respond correctly" mean? What _does_ happen? What _should_ happen?

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me directions, I'm really new to this and the web helped me a lot to get started. I do not intend to get anything with the download of my app I do not have ads or anything is just so that you can see the error in android 9

Comment: Already make the necessary changes, the application works correctly on any device and version, but in android v9 the login and register buttons do not work simply, you do nothing when you press them.

Comment: You haven't included any code related to buttons in the question